# setting variables in a NSUserAutomatorTask

Tags: objective-c, macos, automator

I'm migrating some code from AMWorkflow to NSUserAutomatorTask so that ultimately I can sandbox my app. I'd like to be able to set the value of existing variables within the workflow as was possible in AMWorkflow with:

```
AMWorkflow *task = [[AMWorkflow alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL error:nil];
[task setValue:@"myValue" forVariableWithName:@"myVar"];
```

However I don't seem to be able to get something similar working with NSUserAutomatorTask.
The only documentation I can find (the class reference) says supply the variables as an NSDictionary.

So I'm trying something like:

```
NSUserAutomatorTask * task = [[NSUserAutomatorTask alloc] initWithURL:workflow error:nil];

task.variables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"myValue" forKey:@"myVar"];
[task executeWithInput:nil completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error){
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error while executing workflow %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

I've read in another answer ( [Using AMWorkflow with sandboxed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149529) ) that the value supplied with "executeWithInput:" for NSUserAutomatorTask is ignored. Is it possible the variables are too?

Comment: I added a similar question here. I want to set variables, but only if they are supplied in the workflow itself. Using `NSUserAutomatorTask` the workflow will not run if the variables are not set in the workflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507620/setting-nsuserautomatortask-variables-without-requiring-automator-workflows-to-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did try this when you first posted in 10.8.3 and could not get it to work. I tried various things with no luck.

I am now on 10.8.4 and it now seems to work without any real changes to your basic code.

```
NSUserAutomatorTask * task = [[NSUserAutomatorTask alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"file:///Users/UserName/Desktop/folderActionTest/test.workflow"] error:nil];

NSDictionary* taskDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Test item" forKey:@"Storage"];
task.variables=taskDict;
[task executeWithInput:nil completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error){
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error while executing workflow %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

The workflow is a simple one that that already has a Variable called **Storage** and a choose from list that gets its input from the variable.

[image]

The workflow in action when the code is run.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll retest in 10.8.4

Answer (score 1):

This may help - not tried it yet but looking for same answer

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/AMWorkflow_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AMWorkflow

setValue:forVariableWithName:
Sets the value of the workflow variable with the specified name.

```
- (BOOL)setValue:(id)value forVariableWithName:(NSString *)variableName
```

Parameters
value
The value to set for the named variable.

variableName
The name of a variable to set the value for.

Return Value
YES if variableName was found and its value set; otherwise NO.

Discussion
This method does nothing if the variable specified by variableName is not found.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.5 and later.
Declared In
AMWorkflow.h
valueForVariableWithName:
Returns the value of the workflow variable with the specified name.

```
- (id)valueForVariableWithName:(NSString *)variableName
```

Parameters
variableName
The variable name.

Return Value
The value for the variable. Returns nil if no variable is found with the specified name.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.5 and later.
See Also
– setValue:forVariableWithName:
Declared In
AMWorkflow.h
writeToURL:error

Comment: That's all good stuff (and in fact works) but my problem is finding a way to do the same within the confines of a sandboxed app which restricts me to NSUserAutomatorTask